# Creating has_many :through Association conditionally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following classes:

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
end
```

I want only a Physician to be able to create an Appointment, but not a Patient. Please let me know how I can have this restriction at the Model level.

Thanks!

Comment: When you say you want '...only a Doctor to be able...' do you mean only a Physician?  And if so, what do you mean by a Physician being able to create a record?  A Physician is a record, itself.  Do you mean restricting a user's ability to create Patient records through Appointment records?

Comment: Sorry - yes, I mean only a Physician must be able to create an Appointment. I meant to ask if it be possible to disallow doing something like:
Patient.find(1).appointments << Appointment.create(...)

Comment: I think you're putting too much on the association. The association is just a description of relationships between models. The business behavior around those models isn't an association issue, I don't think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use the association to retrieve patients appointmets. Just create a getter method for them:

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  def appointments
    Appointment.where(patient_id: self.id)
  end
end
```

Comment: This is also not exactly what OP requested, but it is correct and one good way to address the issue.  There's really no need to use an ActiveRecord association in this case.

Comment: Thanks! Just curious - if I do not have this restriction (that a Physician shouldn't be allowed to create an appointment), would you recommend using a getter method or an association?

Comment: Association provides a bunch of helper methods related to it, both getters and setters, and overwriting setters is not a good idea. So you will need to just retrieve the appointments for a patient, meaning everything else is no needed. So the question is not how to disable everything, but how to writte a getter for the patients.   But doctors might need everything, so associations are allowed and recommended.